# Get HTML Divs From PouchDB

Tags: jquery, pouchdb

I'm saving HTML divs to a PouchDB "board" object. I have this function to get all of the saved divs:

```
window.viewBoards = function() {
    var results = db.allDocs({include_docs: true}, function(err, response) { });

}
```

The results have the divs pretty buried in them:

```
Promise {cancel: function, [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: Object}cancel: function (){return this}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: Objectoffset: 0rows: Array[5]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Objectdoc: Object_id: "2014-12-05T20:48:57.327Z"_rev: "1-68823c9c66374d831b482b9a67354301"board: "↵ <div class="square" style="background-color: rgb(162, 136, 99);"></div><div class="square" style="background-color: rgb(25, 108, 184);"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div><div class="square"></div>"__proto__: Objectid: "2014-12-05T20:48:57.327Z"key: "2014-12-05T20:48:57.327Z"value: Object__proto__: Objectlength: 5__proto__: Array[0]total_rows: 5__proto__: Object
```

How can I save the "board" object to a variable to then put into a page with jQuery? I tried using dot notation like this:

```
    var board = results.[[PromiseStatus]]. ???
```

But that [[PromiseStatus]] thing makes it tricky and I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you are seeing is the Promise response. PouchDB has two ways of working with its API: callbacks (i.e. `function (err, response)`) and Promises (e.g. `db.allDocs().then(function (){...}`).

So in your case the best thing to do would be:

```
db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function (results) {
  /* handle results */ 
}).catch(function (error) {
  /* handle error */
})
```

I suggest you take a look at [the PouchDB guide to async code](http://pouchdb.com/guides/async-code.html), and if you get stuck, there are lots of live code samples to help you out! :)